# Concatenating a nested list with differing number of elements

Tags: r, nested-lists

I am a newbie to R and have a concatenation problem that I haven't been able to solve.

I have a huge data frame of the form:

> `station POSIX            date.str forec.time lead.time mean.ens obs`
>
> `6019    2011-08-06 06:00 20110806 00         006       45    67`
>
> `6019    2011-08-06 07:00 20110806 00         007       69    72`
>
> `6031    2011-08-06 12:00 20110806 06         006       87    95`
>
> `6031    2011-08-06 13:00 20110806 06         007       88    97`

I have use "ply" to split the data frame like this

> `mydata.split <- dlply(mydataframe, .(datestr), dlply, .(forec.time), dlply, .(lead.time), identity, .drop  = FALSE)`

I do some calculation with data, which require that data are split up this way. I call this new list mynewlist af calculations. I would like to concatenate these data, but I run into problems because of differing number of list elements.

> `> length(mynewlist[[1]][[1]])`
>
> `[1] 34`
>
> `> length(mynewlist[[1]][[2]])`
>
> `[1] 38`

I have tried to use `do.call( rbind, do.call( rbind, do.call( rbind, mynewlist) ) )` to concatenate the list into a data frame, but I get the following message:

`In function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)`

Is there a way of concatenating a nested list with differing number of elements?

I am greateful for help or a point in a direction.
Regard
Sisse

Comment: Not exactly sure how you mean to concatenate these; each list is to be a row in the new dataframe, but since they are different lengths, each contributes a different number of columns?  If so, what should the additional columns be?  If this is the case, and the blank columns should be `NA`, then maybe replace `rbind` with `rbind.fill`

Comment: And, alternatively, if they new items represent new rows what goes into the unfilled columns on those rows?  You can just blindly fill with NA or by recycling items but do you want to?  `data.frame` class items are rectangular and `list` items are not.  If it's really not rectangular then you can't really turn it into a proper `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ldply` to stitch all those lists back together.

With the `baseball` data in `plyr`, use `dlply` as in your question to spit the data:

```
library(plyr)
x <- dlply(baseball, .(year), transform, mean_rbi = mean(rbi))
```

Now use `ldply` to combine the lists into a `data.frame`:

```
y <- ldply(x)
```

The results:

```
str(y)
'data.frame':   21699 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ id      : chr  "ansonca01" "forceda01" "mathebo01" "startjo01" ...
 $ year    : int  1871 1871 1871 1871 1871 1871 1871 1872 1872 1872 ...
 $ stint   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ team    : chr  "RC1" "WS3" "FW1" "NY2" ...
 $ lg      : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ g       : int  25 32 19 33 29 29 29 46 37 25 ...
 ...
 $ rbi     : int  16 29 10 34 23 21 23 50 15 16 ...
 ...
 $ gidp    : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ mean_rbi: num  22.3 22.3 22.3 22.3 22.3 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However doing "ldply(mynewlist)" gives "Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) : 
  Results must be all atomic, or all data frames" I am affraid, that I don't have any idea, what this means. I can get it to work fine with the baseball dataset. Regards Sisse

Comment: In that case you have possibly added or deleted columns from some of the pieces, but not all.  If you fix that issue in your code, try `ldply` again.